# Rewrite get parameter in url for every page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'd like rewrite this url:

```
xxx.dev:8888/categoryname?gender=girls
```

to

```
xxx.dev:8888/categoryname/girls
```

The `categoryname` will be different so I can't set a specific rule.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for if the key name is static:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?categoryname/(\w+)/?$ /categoryname?gender=$1 [END]
```

Or it might be that your last sentence in the question indicates the opposite, that the key is variable, then this should do what you ask:

```
RewriteEngine on
%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /$1?gender=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

These rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).